# some Triangle pointers are missing when I use callout shape for datalabels

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, highcharts

[look at the bellow example only last data label has triangle pointing shape](https://jsfiddle.net/6d5pLtrh/11/)

```
I wanted all label's to have a triangle pointer.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `callout shape` works fine when all labels are rendered above or next to the point.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dey08qLh/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.dataLabels.shape